# How to list service names in Oracle database with no access to ssh

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Using an Oracle 9i database, is there a method to list all the active service names if I don't know which databases/SIDs/service names are running?

I'm trying to connect but the main error is

> Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12504, TNS:listener was not given the SID in CONNECT_DATA

and if I use the database name the IT manager gave me

> Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

The database is Oracle 9i running on a server in same local network. I obviously have hostname, port, username and password to connect the database (I have **no** access to the server's command line).

I'm trying to connect using Oracle SQL developer (and also tried in PHP 7 using latest PECL library).

Thank you!

Comment: $lsnrctl status. The listener is responsible for exposing the service_names to the world. You can also login "sqlplus / as sysdba" and look into dba_services.

Comment: For lsnrctl I need the command line access in the database machine, that I can't have.  And about connecting as sysdba, when I select the option in oracle sql developer it asks me the service name anyway.

Comment: Do you have an ldap-directory for tns lookup, or a tnsnames.ora file you can query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible to "guess" the SID (there are many techniques as reported in https://erpscan.com/wp-content/uploads/pub/Different%20ways%20to%20guess%20Oracle%20database%20SID.pdf ) but there isn't a straightforward method to get it without accessing a tnsnames.ora or similars.